# Waking an ESP8266 from Light-Sleep using a signal from MQTT?

Tags: esp8266, iot, mqtt

**I was wondering if it would be possible to wake an ESP8266 from a request over MQTT while it is in Light-Sleep mode?** I am planning to implement a smart switch that would receive messages from a Raspberry Pi to turn off and on, however, I don't want to have to manually hit a button to trigger an external reset (I've seen this done in many examples already). I also don't think it would be efficient for me to just set a timer and have the ESP wake up in intervals. For instance, if I want to have the smart switch turn on an appliance and the PI sends a request over MQTT when the ESP is sleeping... this will do me no good. Curious if anyone has run into this issue before and what recommendations you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if it would be possible to wake an ESP8266 from a request over MQTT while it is in Light-Sleep mode?

No. The ESP8266 has to be awake to communicate with the MQTT server.

The best you can hope for is a periodic wakeup to connect to the server and check for any new data.  But of course that relies on the data being set to QOS 2 so it keeps trying to be delivered until the ESP8266 is awake to receive it.